# 'significance level' in a cross correlation analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-correlation

I have time series data and applied the cross correlation function in matlab. We know that the correlation coefficients that are shown in the output are the 'best' values shown with the corresponding lag times. This means that other lags are also tested and found to be 'inferior' or of low correlation.

When I should this to my supervisor, I was asked to look for the significance of the correlation. Now I begin to wonder:

1. Is there such a thing as significance of a cross correlation of time series?
2. What purpose, then, does the significance level serve when you already have a correlation coefficient already?

Insights are welcome.

Comment: I'm not going to do an official answer, cause I've done spatial cross-correlations, not in matlab. But 1. Could do permutations. That's what ncf does for spatial (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncf/ncf.pdf). 2. Two very different things! Correlation is the strenght of the relation. Significance is how probable to observe this value is.

Comment: This MATLAB function will give you the significance: Alex Backer (2020). xcorrpvalue (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/75403-xcorrpvalue), MATLAB Central File Exchange. Retrieved May 7, 2020.